# How to insert sleep into a list

Tags: python, sleep

I am looking to create just a small module to implement the ability to text scroll. I've tried a few things so far and this is what I'm sitting on:

```
from time import sleep

def text_scroll(x):
    x = x.split()
    #here is where I'd like to add the sleep function
    x = " ".join(x)

print x

text_scroll("hello world.")
```

With all this I am hoping to have it print "hello", sleep for a second, "world". The best I've gotten so far is it returning None instead of actually pausing.

Comment: `print x` needs to be indented. Also, what does `sleep(1)` give you?

Comment: Are you using python 2.7 or python 3?

Comment: You need to return something from the function if that's what you're missing.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
from time import sleep
from sys import stdout

def text_scroll(text):
    words = text.split()
    for w in words:
        print w,
        stdout.flush()
        sleep(1)
```

The comma at the end of the print does not add new line '\n'.
The flush() function flushes the word into the screen (standard output).

Comment: My interpreter does not require the stdout.flush()

Comment: I did in *ipython* and it does not flush without flush() call, therefor I added it. Interesting to investigate if flushing is garanteeed somewhere.

Comment: Interesting, +1: from the console interpreter it doesn't work without flush, but PyCharm's console works fine without it.

Apparently PyCharm is doing some magic in the background for me.

Answer (score 0):

If it is python 2.7, you can do the following, which is what volcano suggested.

```
from time import sleep

def text_scroll(x):
    for word in x.split():
        print word,
        sleep(1)

text_scroll("Hello world")
```

This works because it splits the input into individual words and then prints them, sleeping between each word. The `print word,` is python 2.7 for print `word`, without a newline `,`.

Yours doesn't work for several reasons:

```
def text_scroll(x):
    x = x.split()
    #here is where I'd like to add the sleep function
    x = " ".join(x)
```

this function doesn't do anything with the variable that it makes, and it mangles it:

```
def text_scroll(x):
    x = x.split()                 # x = ["Hello", "world"]
    #here is where I'd like to add the sleep function
    x = " ".join(x)               # x = "Hello world"
```

It doesn't actually do anything with the result, so it gets thrown away. But it's also important to realize that because it is a `def`, it doesn't execute until it is called.

when you `print x`, `x` hasn't been set, so it should give you a `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

Finally, you call your function `text_scroll("hello world.")` which doesn't output anything, and it finishes.

Answer (score -2):

```
for word in x.split():
    print word,
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comma prevents *print* from adding line feed to your output

Comment: this works for python 2.7, although you don't need the `time.` if you import as he did.

It's also worth explaining why `print word,` does what is does, and why the `,` is important

Comment: Thank you!  Worked like a charm.